# How can I read .CRe files on Incense Platform?

Tags: debugging

I tried many ways but I cannot launch or read `.CRe` files on the `VDR`. The IDE is saying that the applet is ready. But the Emulator says cannot launch the App. Please Help!!!!!

Comment: Specify how much you have tried out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ReFill the Guardian form of the Applet then the program will be successfully built. And when exported you need to mount to the emulator. That's how you need to work.

Comment: Hello Chamuth Please wait while I try your idea

Comment: And After that you need to update the XENOM(TM) for the latest version before the activity is launched!

Comment: Try the Download option!

Comment: If it does not work try to download the HAXM for Incense